# Does ADAL JS support Implicit flow for adfs 2016?

Tags: angularjs, adal

I am trying to implement implictit flow in angular js using the adal js, but it fetches only the id token as the login is performed only with the ID token, I could also seeing statements to upload the meta data in azure to support implicit flow, will this be handling the access token issuance part in that case I am using adfs 2016 , is there any options to handle this.

Comment: I verified and the reason I could see are the Login function has the response type hard coded as 'idtoken' and it is not including the "token" also the resource is not passed, another issue I could see is that idtoken value is assigned to accesstoken. Any suggestion to have the implicit flow working for adfs 2016?

Answer (score 0):

ADFS currently supports only Authorization Code Flow, below is the confirmation on the same

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/maheshu/2015/04/28/oauth-2-0-support-in-adfs-on-windows-server-2012-r2/